# Log4j.properties on classpath but not loaded

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I'm using maven and the one-jar plugin to build my project and I have my `log4j.properties` in `src/main/resources`. I've used the `one-jar.verbose` to check that is on the classpath and other properties files in the same directory are being successfully used by the program. However when I run it I still get the following error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Using `BasicConfigurator.configure()` is a quick fix, but I need it to be in an external config file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appender I'd configured in `log4j.properties`, I hadn't added to `log4j.rootLogger=...`